# Definition of Clique vertex and separator vertex

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

While converting a tree decomposition of graph to Normalized tree decomposition, the definitions of clique vertex and separator vertex are used in 
[Sequential and parallel algorithms for embedding problems on classes of partial k-trees](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-58218-5_16)
page: 8-9. 
Can somebody help me out with the two definitions which are used there.

Comment: Look at the beginning of Section 3.1, where normalized tree decompositions are defined.  When the authors say that the vertices of $T^H$ alternate between separator vertices and clique vertices, I take this to mean that every child of a separator vertex is a clique vertex, and every child of a clique vertex is a separator vertex.  I hope this clarifies the situation -- they are intrinsic to the definition of a normalized tree decomposition.